# Excel =+ formula impact

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I can't for the life of me remember but what does putting `+` after `=` in a formula actually do?

For example the difference between:

`=+VLookup(A1,B1:B10,1,FALSE)`

Compared with:

`=VLookup(A1,B1:B10,1,FALSE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must admit I never encountered it previously, but from what I could dig up, looks like it has no meaning, and is just a history piece for people used to Lotus.

An article about [differences between Excel and Lotus by Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculation-differences-between-microsoft-excel-and-lotus-1-2-3-formulas-HP005198694.aspx):

> In Excel, you start a formula with an equal sign (=). You can also start a formula with a plus sign (+), as you would in Lotus 1-2-3.

and if you use just a plus sign, it gets translated to `=+`.

Comment: I know that `+formula(args)` and `=formula(args)` (as the user entering a formula) are interpreted identically in most cases. I did find an exception to this at some point, but I can't remember what it was off the top of my head :-( - if I recall it or stumble on it again, and if I remember to come back here, I'll post it and let you know, just in case you're interested

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in Excel 2013 the =+ can cause problems in a formula such as this:

=+'AA'!B2+'BB'!B2 gives an incorrect calculation.

Changing the =+ to just = corrects the problem.  This is random, not consistent. It can still cause quite an issue with financial information.

Comment: This would be better served as a comment to the accepted answer.